# Ranking Over Row_Number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ranking-functions

I am posting a sample data below.

[image]

What I have is a row number which generated a number based on Date and Name columns (achieved using ROW_NUMBER function). What I need now, is another derived column called Group_Num which creates a number for each group (3 in this case). Can this be achieved considering the fact that my Name column repeats but the Date column value changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please remove the picture and add sample data as DDL + DML, and also show the query you currently have.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check This.
We can achive this using Row_number() ,lag() and SUM() .

```
        select 
        Date,
        Name,
        Row_number()over( partition by Group_Num order by ROwiD ) Row_Num,
        Group_Num
        from 
        (
            SELECT * ,  
            SUM(R) OVER(ORDER BY RowID) Group_Num
            FROM
            (
                select *,
                Case When 
                lag(name ) OVER (ORDER BY RowID ) = name
                then 0  else 1 end  as R 
                from 
                    (
                        select DATE,NAME,
                        row_number() OVER (    ORDER BY  (select 1)) AS 'RowID'
                        from #TableName
                    )A
            )B
         )C
        order by ROwiD
```

> OutPut :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I use this, it will return the Group_Num as "1" for the last 3 rows. I need it as 3 (even though the name is same).

Answer (score 2):

You can use DENSE_RANK:

```
SELECT Date
    , Name
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Name Order By Name, Date) as Row_Num
    , DENSE_RANK() Over(order by Name) as Group_Num 
FROM #Table
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I use this, it will return the Group_Num as "1" for the last 3 rows. I need it as 3 (even though the name is same).